# WebShere Custom login portlet UNAUTHENTICATED Principal

Tags: authentication, websphere, jaas, websphere-portal, ltpa

I have a JSF portlet Application with a custom JSF login portlet that uses the `portletservice/com.ibm.portal.portlet.service.login.LoginHome` to log in users,

after successful login I try the following code:

```
WSSubject.getRunAsSubject(),
```

it gives me, `Subject:Principal: /UNAUTHENTICATED`

But if I login into the portal using the portal login original portlet, and test the same code, it gives me `Subject:Principal: defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/wpsadmin`

Can anyone tell me where is the problem, do I need any extra configuration, I need the Run-as subject to propagate the generated LTPA token.

Update 1:

```
 LoginService loginService = (LoginService) loginHome.getLoginService(getRequestWrapper().getPortletRequest() ,getResponseWrapper().getPortletResponse()); 
 Map<String,Object> contextMap = new HashMap<String,Object>();
 contextMap.put(LoginService.DO_RESUME_SESSION_KEY, new Boolean(true));
 loginService.login(getUserID(), getUserPassword().toCharArray(), contextMap, null);
```

Comment: can you share the code where you use LoginHome?

Comment: LoginService loginService = (LoginService) loginHome.getLoginService(getRequestWrapper().getPortletRequest()
                    ,getResponseWrapper().getPortletResponse());
   Map<String,Object> contextMap = new HashMap<String,Object>();
   contextMap.put(LoginService.DO_RESUME_SESSION_KEY, new Boolean(true));
   loginService.login(getUserID(), getUserPassword().toCharArray(), contextMap, null);

Comment: I checked other samples like http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21358508 and the only difference from the code  is LoginService.DO_RESUME_SESSION_KEY, new Boolean(false). You use true. I know the default login Portlet does not try to recreate the old session. Do you really need this feature, if not I would give it a try with false. In any case you could check traces for the Loginservice .. in addition a good writeup on the function http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0905_buchwald/0905_buchwald.html

Comment: i have already tried that but with no luck, the strange thing is that i removed the line of code WSSubject.getRunAsSubject() to the next action after the login, and now it returns the expected result of the already authenticated user.it seems like the login service is asynchronous and querying the Rn-as subject immediately after login results in a wrong result due to the fact that the token and subject are still not created at this moment

Comment: with "next action" you mean the next request or where in the code of the current request do you get Null and where the authenticated User

Comment: i meant the next request, trying to get the run-as subject immediately after calling  loginService.login, always resulted in unauthenticated principal as if the subject is not yet created